# Run workflow for item expiration

Tags: workflow

As I understand WF are triggered with events (or event). I have an expiration column and I need to send notifications 45 and 30 days prior to the expiration data. What are my options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at my answer over on [StackOverflow.com - Dated Reminders in SharePoint ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529045/dated-reminders-in-sharepoint-calendars)

It's basically the same problem. That poster is looking to remind people of upcoming calendar events but this is no different to your use case of emails before expiry dates.

The post talks about a few different ways to do this

- Workflow
- Timer Jobs
- Open source solutions
- Commercial Solutions

Comment: IRM is another possibility in conjunction with workflows

Answer (score 6):

You can trigger the workflow when the item is created, then pause it until you reach the expiration date minus 30 (or 45) days. This can easily be done with SharePoint Designer.

This could become tricky if the expiration date is modified later. If it is the case you'll need to rely on more advanced solutions (e.g. recurring workflows that poll the item at regular intervals).

Comment: +1. To add: no "tricks" needed, since parallel blocks are avaliable in SharePoint 2010. Have just implemented this and tested - works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use [Alerts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897925.aspx). If I'm not wrong in ItemAdded event of List item receiver you can create Alert, set AlertTime to needed time, set AlertFrequency to Immediate.

Comment: This won't work either - SharePoint Alerts are triggered in response to user actions (like adding/editing a record) and you can't use that Schema to schedule an alert for a specific time in the future

Comment: @Ryan  As I know the alerts are started by timer job. This job selects alerts that have alert time less then current time and sends notification. Then it increase time to interval for weekly and daily alerts. So in my schema alerts are not set by the system, the code sets alert in event handler. Am I miss something?

Comment: Thats not how I understood AlertTime to work. Have you actually got this working?

Comment: I have never used this idea. Thus I use "if I'm not wrong" phrase... I hope that I will have a time to check this solution tomorrow.

Comment: My solution is wrong. There are each item should have its own alert. But it is not possible. Thanks that you corrected me.

Answer (score 0):

Create views with the specified criteria, then subscribe alerts to the views.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Ryan's poking and my desire to prove myself, I did discover this isn't as straight forward as I thought. You need to create a view with no date filtering, but you need some kind of filtering, like Title does not contain [blank]. Then subscribe to that view, then change the filter to your desired date filter. This works for me. I'm curious to see if it does for you.

Comment: You won't be able to set an alert on a view with a filter containing Today (needed for the 45/30 day expiration)

Comment: Sure you can, i do it all the time.

Comment: I'll bet you a pint you can't ;)

Comment: tryin it right now ;) I've done it before, lets see if i can again

Comment: what the crap! Tried on Sp2010, I got this to work before on a WSS3 view, a few times... i think... I owe you one, next time you're in town!

Comment: ok, sorry for the spazzing comments... i did get it to work, created a normal view, subscribed to it, then changed the filter to by date. BLAMO

Comment: Yup - but does your Alert actually work? Setup a test list like the OP's with an alert to come out Monday and I promise you won't get it. Mines a Kronenberg ;)

Comment: Ok, i will. i tested it by adding a new item within the filter value (and outside the filter value) and it worked as planned