# Execute a retention stage (expiration policy) only for items that are bigger than some specified size

Tags: 2010, information-management, expiration

In Information Management Policies, one can set a retention policy for an item, e.g. if item is older than 3 years, then move it to recycle bin. You can then apply this policy to a content type in a library. Is it possible (out of the box) to get a retention policy to only execute if an item (a document) is e.g. bigger than 3 MB? How could I make something like that?

Ideally, I'd like to specify other filters as well, so that effectively you get a retention policy that looks like: "if item is older than 3 years AND is bigger than 3 MB AND is .pptx or .docx -> then move it to recycle bin". When creating a policy, right now all I can get is: "if item is older than X -> move it to recycle bin".

Can this be done out of the box, without creating custom projects that require coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't beleive it's possible out of box.

> To use a custom retention formula to determine expiration, click Set
>   by a custom retention formula installed on this server.  NOTE    This
>   option is only available if a custom formula has been set up by your
>   administrator.

[Reference: Create and apply information management policies](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-and-apply-information-management-policies-HA101631505.aspx#_Toc262125406)

However you can create a custom retention policy, follow this article for doing it by code.

[Creating custom retention policies for SharePoint 2010 libraries](http://www.sharemuch.com/2011/01/10/creation-custom-retention-policies-for-sharepoint-2010-libraries/)

OR

You start a approval workflow for item which is about to expire.

[Run workflow for item expiration](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23109/how-to-run-workflow-for-item-expiration)